# Application Insights SDK C# - Log full telemetry and dependencies only on requests that have failed

Tags: c#, .net, azure-application-insights

We're trying to cut down the costs of our Application Insights instance, currently we don't have Adaptive Sampling enabled as we find it often doesn't record a dependency that is required so doesn't give us a full picture, especially when a request has failed.

So my thinking was to only log the Request without any dependencies if the request was successful, and log all the Dependencies if the Request was not successful.

I thought this would be fairly easy using the TelemetryProcessor Filter functionality. However, as far as I can see there is no link within the SDK between the telemetry i.e. I cannot see how a Request telemetry links to the Dependency telemetry, meaning I cannot stop the SDK logging the Dependency as I cannot check if the Request was successful.

The WebAPI is running .Net6, C# using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.20.0

Has anyone else had this problem or can think of a solution? Many thanks

Comment: That will be really difficult, if not impossible, to do as indeed a `TelemetryProcessor` process all telemetry items individually. You could write your own [telemetry channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/telemetry-channels) that inspects the buffered telemetry and remove items from there but even that will be hard because you do not know when the request is done and no dependency telemetry will be generated anymore.

Comment: *However, as far as I can see there is no link within the SDK between the telemetry* There is, it is the operation_Id included in every telemetry.See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation) for more details.

Comment: I concur with @PeterBons, the challenge here is that you want to decide if something is logged or not based on something that happens in the future. The core idea of AI logging is that things can be logged independently and then correlated afterward with correlation IDs. You could implement something on your own, however, I personally have tackled similar cost-saving goals by disabling dependency logging (JDBC in my case) from non-critical environments. For critical environments, it's just an accepted cost.